# Why is the precision of numpy output different each time?

Tags: numpy, floating-point, decimal, precision, bit

Run the following program:

```
for i in range(10):
    a = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    print(a)
```

We have the result:

```
0.4418517709510906
0.05536715253773261
0.44633855235431785
0.3143041997189251
0.16175184090609163
0.8822875281567105
0.11367473012241913
0.9951703577237277
0.009103257465210124
0.5185580156093157
```

Why is the precision of each output different? Sometimes accurate to 16 decimal places, but sometimes accurate to 18 decimal places. **Why does this happen?**

Also, if I want to control the precision of the output, i.e., only 15 decimal places are output each time, how can I do this?

---

**Edit:** I try to use `np.set_printoptions(precision=15)`

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=15)
for i in range(10):
    a = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    print(a)
```

But the output is:

```
0.3908531691561824
0.6363290508517755
0.3484260990246082
0.23792451272035053
0.5776808805593472
0.3631616619602701
0.878754651138258
0.6266540814279749
0.8309347174000745
0.5763464514883537
```

This still doesn't get the result I want. The result I want is something like below:

```
0.390853169156182
0.636329050851775
0.348426099024608
0.237924512720350
0.577680880559347
0.363161661960270
0.878754651138258
0.626654081427974
0.830934717400074
0.576346451488353
```

Comment: @JérômeRichard I've put the attempt in the problem description and I still don't get the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(a)` prints the shortest numeric string that yields the same float64 value as `a`.

Example:

```
a = 0.392820481778549002
b = 0.392820481778549
a_bits = np.asarray(a).view(np.int64).item()
b_bits = np.asarray(b).view(np.int64).item()

print(f"{a:.18f}", hex(a_bits))
print(f"{b:.18f}", hex(b_bits))
print(a == b)
```

Result:

```
0.392820481778549002 0x3fd923f8849c0570
0.392820481778549002 0x3fd923f8849c0570
True
```

You can use the `f"{a:.18f}"` syntax to get fixed-width output. The equivalent for numpy arrays is `np.set_printoptions(precision=18, floatmode="fixed")`.

Comment: If I want to write the result to a txt file, how should I program it? I tried a command like ‘f.write('{}'.format(f"{a:.18f}))’ and it will report an error

Comment: `with open("numbers.txt", "w") as f: f.write(f"{a:.18f}")`

Comment: By the way, What is the difference between f.write(f"{a:.18f}") and f.write('%.18f' % a), their output seems to be the same.

Comment: In this case there's no difference, but the f-string syntax (introduced in Python 3) is more flexible and nowadays recommended.